# Boot from USB drive on Chromebook Acer C721

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bootloader, chromebook

I have set my Chromebook Acer C721 in developer mode, and permitted USB booting via `sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 dev_boot_legacy=1`. Then, after the next reboot, at the developer mode warning, I type CTRL-L, and I'm presented with two boot loader options: U-Boot and TianoCore. The latter one does nothing (TianoCore does not load, need to reboot after selecting it), while the former one takes me to the U-Boot prompt.

I have plugged in a USB stick with Ubuntu 20.04.3 for amd64. I had pulled that image from the Ubuntu web site and dd'ed it to the USB stick. It now has two partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 7.2 GiB, 7776239616 bytes, 15187968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x....

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *          0 5999871 5999872  2.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sdd2       5271500 5279499    8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

When U-Boot starts up, it says

```
...
scanning bus 0 for devices... 4 USB Device(s) found
scanning bus 1 for devices... 4 USB Device(s) found
...
```

When I leave it to autoboot, it says

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Error: Invalid Boot Flag (found 0x0000, expected 0xaa55)
```

However, the first 512 bytes on the stick (sector 1) end with this boot signature.

U-Boot detects the USB stick as per the output of `usb storage` and `usb tree`.

But how can I boot from it?

I tried `usbboot 0700 0:0` (assuming 0700 is the start address for the first-level boot loader on the USB drive), which results in

```
Loading from usb device 0, partition 0, Name: While Disk  Type: U-Boot
** Unknown image type
```

`usbboot 0700 0:1` results in

```
** Invalid partition 1 **
```

And `usbboot 0700 0:2` results in

```
Loading from usb device 0, partition 2, Name: usbda2  Type: U-Boot
** Unknown image type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had forgotten to apply [Mr. Chromebox's firmware scripts](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript)
to set the RW_LEGACY flag. After doing that, I could load TianoCore, which presented me with a boot menu to boot from USB stick, SD card (provided a medium was in the slot), or eMMC. Selecting USB or SD then loaded the boot loader from that medium, and everything from there was golden.