# Boot from USB on a HP Chromebook

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to swap operating systems on a Chromebook I have, going from ChromeOS to Tiny11 (originally gonna be Linux Mint 21). I have done the needed steps to get USB booting to work but I have to use U-boot because the second one (TianoCore) doesn't work.

I have the USB flashed and inserted into the Chromebook but I keep getting this weird error:

```
Error: Invalid Boot Flag (found 0x0000, expected 0xaa55)
## Kernel loading failed ...
zboot - Boot bzImage
    
[junk on how zboot works]
=>
```

I tried using `usbboot mmc 0:1` but that keeps sending me back to the OS Verification screen and not booting into Tiny11. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: sounds like https://superuser.com/questions/1701140/boot-from-usb-drive-on-chromebook-acer-c721